# Java - Escaped backslashes being taken literally when writing to file

Tags: java, string, escaping

I want to store a URL in a properties file. This is the URL:

```
jdbc\:sqlserver\://dummydata\\SHARED
```

When programming this in Java, I obviously need to escape the backslashes. So my code ends up looking like this

```
properties.setProperty("db", "jdbc\\:sqlserver\\://dummydata\\\\SHARED");
```

The issue with this is that the properties file is saving the String URL and including the backslashes used for escaping, which is an incorrect URL. I was hoping that Java would interpret the backslashes used for escaping so that only the correct URL is saved. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You shouldn't have backslashes in a URL in the first place: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017). But anyway, reading the property using the Properties class will unescape those backslashes.

Comment: Actually, with the backslashes (the single ones) this is not a valid URL. At least, "jdbc\" is not a valid scheme.

Comment: @RealSkeptic perhaps URL was not the right word. It is just a link to an SQL database within our company. The single slashes work for me and have been connecting to the database with no issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that a property value with `:` needs to escape the colons in a `.properties` *text file*, but you're not writing that text file directly.

You are giving the value to a `Properties` object using `setProperty()`, and presumably writing that to a *text file* using `store()`, and the `store()` method will **escape the values as needed for you**.

You should give the value you want to `Properties`, and forget about the encoding rules of the *text file*. `Properties` will handle all needed encoding. Since the value you want to give is `jdbc:sqlserver://dummydata\SHARED`, you write a *string literal* `"jdbc:sqlserver://dummydata\\SHARED"`

*Example*

```
String db = "jdbc:sqlserver://dummydata\\SHARED";
System.out.println(db); // To see actual string value

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("db", db);
try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter("test.properties")) {
    properties.store(out, null);
}
```

*Output*

```
jdbc:sqlserver://dummydata\SHARED
```

*Content of test.properties*

```
#Tue Jun 11 11:54:24 EDT 2019
db=jdbc\:sqlserver\://dummydata\\SHARED
```

As you can see, the `store()` method has escaped the `:` and `\` for you.

---

If you save the properties as an XML file instead, there's no need to escape anything, and `Properties` won't.

*Example*

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.xml")) {
    properties.storeToXML(out, null);
}
```

*Content of test.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="db">jdbc:sqlserver://dummydata\SHARED</entry>
</properties>
```

Comment: this makes total sense and was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Properties.store()` escapes backslashes, there is no way around it. I guess my first question is why is this an issue? Are you reading the file in any other way than using `Properties.load()`. If not they you don't need to worry about it as the load function will remove the escape characters.

```
   properties.load(file);
   System.out.println(properties.get("db")); 
   // output: jdbc\:sqlserver\://dummydata\\SHARED
```

As an aside are you sure you the URL is correct? Shouldn't you be storing it as `properties.setProperty("jdbc:sqlserver://dummydata\SHARED")`?

Answer (score -1):

In [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) for `load`, it says the following:

> The method does not treat a backslash character, \, before a non-valid escape character as an error; the backslash is silently dropped. For example, in a Java string the sequence "\z" would cause a compile time error. In contrast, this method silently drops the backslash. Therefore, this method treats the two character sequence "\b" as equivalent to the single character 'b'.

This means that two backslashes will be treated as a single one because it's not a valid escape sequence. Loading this string should work just fine:

```
C:\\path\\to\\file
```

Comment: OP's problem is *saving* a properties file, for later re-load. OP should not be escaping the value in the first place, since `Properties` will do that. OP is simply mistaken when thinking that the value needs to be escaped when giving it as a string literal in Java code. It only needs to be escaped when giving it directly in a properties text file. So although your answer is correct, it is not useful to the issue of the question.